# Trouble with Jasper and getCallerClassLoader()

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm trying to get a runtime reference to a compiled subreport that lies in the same directory as my main report.  After hours of googling, I've tried to get the file reference as a URL using the following:

```
new String(
  ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader().toString().substring( 
    ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader().toString().indexOf("=") + 1, 
    ClassLoader.getCallerClassLoader().toString().lastIndexOf("/") ).toString() ) + 
  "/some.jar/com/foo/reports/ThatDamnedReport/ThatDamnedReport_subreport1.jasper"
```

When I debug, I can change the value of my string with the above statement and it works! Yay!

### Problem 1

We're using pre-compiled jasper files and I can only compile up to version 3.1.4 (otherwise the rest of the ancient code breaks).  The "standard" way of accessing my subreport doesn't work because I can't find the relative directory to my subreport.  We're not using JasperServer.

### Problem 2

When I compile via iReport, I get the the error "the method getCallerClassLoader from the type ClassLoader is not visible"

Since I'm trying to compile from a JRXML file, subclassing is not an option here.

### Question

How can I get my file to compile or how do I find the relative path to `ThatDamnedReport_subreport1.jasper`?

Comment: Provide some more details about what you are trying to do, and the environmental constraints. Listing the environments that JasperReports is running would be helpful. (For example, IIS, Servlet, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JasperReports uses an absolute path to find files. To work around this issue do the following:

1. Create a `DIR_ROOT` parameter.
2. Assign a default value for `DIR_ROOT` of `/path/to/com/foo/reports/` (not inside a JAR file; the trailing slash is important).
3. Create a `DIR_SUBREPORT` parameter.
4. Define `DIR_SUBREPORT` relative to `$P{DIR_ROOT}`. For example: `$P{DIR_ROOT} + "ThatDamnedReport/"` (keep the trailing slash).
5. Reference subreports: `$P{DIR_SUBREPORT} + "ThatDamnedReport_subreport1.jasper"`.

When you run the report, if the root directory is different, pass the `DIR_ROOT` parameter to the report. This allows you to keep the subreports relative to the root directory and have the root directory vary between environments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dave.  The trouble is that the code must be portable across platforms too.  I can't assign a default dir (at least, I can't see how that will work). I've also tried using the WEB-INF/classes dir. It found the subreport then, but the versions "conflicted".  I don't have the message with me now, but it was apparently a problem in how the jasper binaries were created.  I even recompiled both main and subreport with the same compiler, but still that error persisted.  I could call it as a File and not a URL from WEB-INF.

Comment: @Rick: I've used this technique on Windows and Unix platforms. For Servlet-based applications you can use the Servlet API to acquire the true path to the report file. Another mechanism would be to create a symbolic link. (Symbolic links are possible on some Windows platforms; you need a special tool.)

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm sorry that I missed your message.  The thing is, it found the file with no problem.  Jasper then threw an error saying that the binary being called was created with a dirrent version of iReport (although, I fail to see how: I recompiled iReport 3.1.4 and generated the jasper file.  Still threw the error).

Comment: @Rick: Post the full stack trace of the errors in your question. Also post a minimal JRXML file that shows how to recreate the error. Also, since "Jasper" could mean "JasperReports Server" or "JasperReports", please be explicit. I'd also like to see your CLASSPATH settings and directory list of all the JAR files you are using. My guess is that you think one version of JasperReports is being used but the Java Virtual Machine is picking up a different version.